# How to show star operator is independ to choice of coordinate ?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra

How to show  star operator is independ to choice of coordinate ?  In fact , I don't know how to present $e_1\wedge ...\wedge e_p$ .

> [image]

Comment: That last formula looks incorrect, if $p\not = d$. For instance, take $p=1$ and $d=2$, and $Ae_1 = a e_1 + be_2$. Then $*Ae_1= a e_2 - b e_1$. The correct formula should have the appropriate minors.

Comment: @peterag  I agree with you . If don't care about the last formula, do you know how to show the independ of star operator with coordinate ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'coordinates' here? Not the coordinates on the manifold?

Comment: @peterag  I mean the star operator is independ  to choice of coordinate .

Comment: What coordinates? There are none in the snippet you pasted in. Agree? Actually, rereading the above, your pasted-in selection, I think it's a bit odd: typically, the Hodge operator is defined in terms of an oriented orthonormal basis - not an arbitrary oriented basis. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual

Comment: (cont) Though, I suppose, one could take the ordered basis and define the metric in terms of it. (And I must confess I am only familiar with Hodge operator in the positive definite situation.)

Comment: @peterag  Sorry for my English. I want to prove  that if choose another positive basis , the star operator is invariable.